# R Incorrect show shape file

Tags: r, ggplot2, gis, shapes, shapefile

I try to open shape file in R from [this site](https://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/50m-cultural-vectors/)

```
shape        <- readOGR(dsn = "/home/user/QGis/50m_physical", layer = "ne_50m_land")
shape_bord   <- readOGR(dsn = "/home/user/QGis/50m_cultural", layer = "ne_50m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land")

map<- ggplot()+
geom_polygon(data = shape, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "black", fill = NA)+
geom_polygon(data = shape_bord, aes(x = long, y = lat, group = group), colour = "green", fill = NA)
```

Some of files has double line in administrative borders.

How can I solve this problem?

[image]
https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land.zip

Comment: We cannot open your data source. Please a reproducible example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: The link is to a page with a lot of files. Which are your files? Moreover, you should double check if data is just that way (with double lines)

Comment: Admin 0 – Boundary Lines,

Comment: https://www.naturalearthdata.com/http//www.naturalearthdata.com/download/50m/cultural/ne_50m_admin_0_boundary_lines_land.zip